# How to set minimum and maximum value of pinch gesture recognizer in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, pinchzoom

I need to set minimum and and maximum value of pinch gesture from 0 to 1 in swift.
Is there any way to do that?

Basically what i need is replacing slider into pinch gesture, I have a chart view in my app and there is a slider which is used to change value of chart. Similarly I want to implement pinch gesture instead of slider, More precisely  the value must be change accordingly when pinching on the chart. Also I need to limit pinching range into 0 to 1 (Pinch scale).

Comment: You mean distance? What do 0 and 1 refer to?

Comment: minimum and maximum value

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not easy to picture, but if you want to allow users to use pinch to zoom a view while keeping the zooming constrained to a minimum and maximum value, you could simply make use of a UIScrollView and make it zoomable, and put some other view inside of it to represent something that needs to be pinched.

For zooming you need to implement a UIScrollViewDelegate and implement `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`, as explained in the UIScrollView documentation. Set the UIScrollView's `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` properties to constrain it. The zoom scale will be within your minimum and maximum range, and you can then convert it to your slider-like value.

Comment: To be clear, this means you don't need to create a pinch gesture recognizer. Let the UIScrollView do it for you.